# Ajax Autocomplete Stored Procedure ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I'm trying to add an autocomplete feature to an asp.net webpage using AJAX AutoCompleteExtender.
I would like to be able to do this through a stored procedure (MS_SQL) but I can't seem to find an example.
I've Created a WebService and tried putting the code in but I'm new to AJAX and nothing seems to work.

SQL:

```
  IF @Statement='AjaxSearch'
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT
            a_AccomName
        FROM SB_ACCOMMODATION
        WHERE a_AccomName like @prefixText
    END
```

C# (WebserviceForAJAX.asmx.cs) :

```
  using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Atlas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    //[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            AtlasInterface conn = new AtlasInterface();
            SqlCommand cmdStoredProcedure = new SqlCommand("ATLAS_ACCOMMODATION", conn.sbConn);
            cmdStoredProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@Statement", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "AjaxSearch";
            cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.Char).Value = prefixText;

            conn.sbConn.Open();
            List<string> customers = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmdStoredProcedure.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(sdr["a_AccomName"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.sbConn.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query works fine ? 

I do not see the `%` wild card char, I believe you may have to put it there.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this : 

`http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74107f/using-stored-procedure-in-autocomplete-extender-textbox-in-a/`

Comment: Thanks, I've added in the Wildcard to the Where clause in the SQL 

  'WHERE a_AccomName like @prefixText+'%''

Comment: Hi Rohit , The link appears to be too short?

Comment: I do not know what is the issue with the link.

In google search for "autocompleteextender stored procedure" and open the fiest link.

Comment: I used a couple of examples and got it working.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have created an asmx web service and you have set the ServiceMethod property on you control but not `ServicePath` which means it is looking for a page method in the web page that contains it. You need to set the `ServicePath` property to the Url of your web service.

e.g.

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
    ServicePath="YourService.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added in the ScriptPath
'    ScriptPath="WebServiceForAjax.asmx"'
But It's not populating still, I think there will be a problem with the code in the webservice as this is new to me. I took an example online and changed it.
I will need a link to the Script in the HTML Though you are right, however it's still not populating the list.